# Ruby - Convert array to hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I loop on this array (Time instances):

`[2018-05-23 8:00:00, 2018-05-23 8:30:00, 2018-05-23 9:30:00, 2018-05-24 15:00:00, 2018-05-24 15:30:00]`

And I would like to convert it to a hash like this :

`{"2018-05-23"=>["2018-05-23 8:00:00", "2018-05-23 8:30:00"], "2018-05-24"=>[]}`

Thanks !

Comment: What kind of objects do you have in your initial array? Strings or Time instances or something else?

Comment: @Stefan Time instances !

Comment: And you want `string => [string, string]` pairs in your hash instead of maybe `date => [time, time]`?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter. Both are okay

Comment: Noémie, your question states that you wish to return a hash whose keys and values are strings. Your comment above, which states that the hash could instead contain `Time` objects, causes two potential problems. The first is that it changes the question. Any change or clarification to a question should be done by editing the question, not by elaborating in comments, for the simple reason that not everyone reads all comments. Suppose, for example, an answer were posted which produced a hash whose values were `Time` objects. (cont.)

Comment: ...A reader who had missed your comment might downvote that answer because it was inconsistent with what you asked for in the question. Also, it's obviously problematic to change a question after an answer has been posted. (cont.)

Comment: ...The second problem is that by saying that the desired return value could be any of two or more Ruby objects (e.g., containing strings or `Time` objects), you may be making it difficult to compare answers. In general, if you ask for "A or B", it could be that producing "A" is simple but deriving "B" is much more complex, even if "A" and "B" seem very similar. It's best to just ask for "A". I know you're newish to SO, so please don't take my comments as a criticism.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
input = ['2018-05-23 8:00:00', '2018-05-23 8:30:00',
         '2018-05-23 9:30:00', '2018-05-24 15:00:00', '2018-05-24 15:30:00']
input.group_by { |e| DateTime.parse(e).to_date.to_s }
#⇒ {"2018-05-23"=>["2018-05-23 8:00:00", "2018-05-23 8:30:00", "2018-05-23 9:30:00"],
#   "2018-05-24"=>["2018-05-24 15:00:00", "2018-05-24 15:30:00"]}
```

Comment: I have Time instances in my array, not Strings

Comment: @NoémieHarvey the block simply returns the key for that item. Items with the same key end up in the same array. If you have time instances, you could use `group_by(&:to_date)` and they will be grouped by their respective dates.

Comment: @Stefan thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for :)